# ListView Windows 8 multiple indexes

Tags: listview, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, c++-cx

When you have a `ListView` in Windows 8 Metro Style Apps how can you get all the indexes selected supposing you have multiple selection enabled?

```
void itemsChanged (Platform::Object^ sender, 
      Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Controls::SelectionChangedEventArgs^ e 
{
    // get selected indexes
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution with the suggestions received

```
auto v = itemsListView->SelectedItems;
auto l = itemsListView->Items;

std::list <unsigned int> v1;
for (int i=0; i < v->Size; i++)
{
            unsigned int k;
            l->IndexOf(v->GetAt(i),&k);
            v1.push_back(k);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You would have to compare the [SelectedItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.selecteditems.aspx) property of the sender (the ListView) with the [Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.items.aspx) property.  It appears that SelectedItems add to the collection and remove from the collection in the order items were selected (although this is not documented anywhere I can find).

Answer (score 1):

You could add index properties to the type of item you bind to your `ListView`. Other than that - perhaps you don't really need an index?