# How to get selected values from multiple selected listview in xam/c#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have listview with multiple selection in xaml, I want to get selected values from this listview.I have also checked different solutions here but couldn't get feasible for me.

I was trying like that

```
  var selectedItems = lstVRecycle.SelectedItems;
  foreach (ListViewItem selectedItem in selectedItems)
  {
        selectedItems.values
  }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What problem do you exactly have? Your code doesn't compile. What do you want to do in the line with "selectedItems.values"?

Comment: I want to get selected items values either in array or some thing else

Comment: How do you populate ListView? Do you bind to a collection of strings, integers, your custom class...?

Comment: my webservice return a class which is binding to the listview

Comment: class have 2 attributes id and name

Comment: Can somebody here help me with this problem ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20708957/c-sharp-metro-xaml-designing-the-page-for-any-of-the-screen

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

> I am using webservice which return list of custom class(Id,Name) so
>   I did initialized my listview itemsource to the list, and multiple
>   selection in enable. so now i want to get id (in array) of all
>   selected items of listview.

`sourceList` is the Your webservice which return list

```
     lstVRecycle.ItemsSource = sourceList //Your webservice which return list

     List<int> setOfItems = new List<int>();
        var selectedItems = lstVRecycle.SelectedItems;
        foreach (var item in selectedItems)
        {
           var value = lstVRecycle.Items.IndexOf(item);
           setOfItems.Add(value);
        }
```

`setofItems` contains index of selected items

```
            List<string> selectedItemIds = new List<string>();
            foreach (var ids in setOfItems) // setOfItems contains index of your selected items
            {
                var value= sourceList[ids];
                String idValue = value.id; //id is your id Value
                selectedItemIds.Add(idValue);
            }
```

Check `selectedItemIds` with set a break-point you have all idValues

It works perfectly. Just take care of your datatypes;
 & We are here to help not to guess.with out proper reply & proper info about your problem you never get answer what you want. Good luck

Comment: sorry couldn't get you, what is itemSelect?

Comment: @AliRaza Please Look at my Edit.. Let me know is this working or not..! Here it is best source [http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ListViewSimple-d5fc27dd ] 
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14861293/listview-windows-8-multiple-indexes ]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you bind the *ListView* to a collection of objects of type *Test* (which has *Id* and *Name* properties) you can retrieve an array of ids of selected items in the following way:

```
var selectedItems = lstVRecycle.SelectedItems.OfType<Test>().Select(o => o.Id).ToArray();
```

My XAML looks as follows:

```
<ListView x:Name="lstVRecycle" SelectionMode="Multiple" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

In this example *Data* is the collection of objects of type *Test*.

Comment: It is not a full solution. You have to customize it according to your needs. Besides, only based on "its not working" I can't do anything. You have to be more specific and give me more details what exactly is not working.

Comment: I am using webservice which return list of custom class(Id,Name) so I did initialized my listview itemsource to the list, and multiple selection in enable.

so now i want to get id (in array) of all selected items of listview.

Comment: Instead of binding item source in XAML I've just tried to populate ItemSource property in C# i.e.: lstVRecycle.ItemsSource = new List<T> {...} and it works. What exactly do not work if you use my code?